# Review audit - good question or duplicate?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

Today [I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8408038) "[existential types declarations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382469/existential-types-declarations-in-scala)" in triage:

I marked it as a duplicate, based on the comment stating that there was an answer in another question, and the OP stating that they found the answer in that same question.

I failed the audit because the question was clear and answerable (it was, but I think it was also a duplicate).  I'm not really worried about failing the audit, but I am not sure what I was supposed to do in this case.

Comment: I voted to close as a dup as the OP added the dup in there own question.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me at some point, I just went to the question and voted to close as duplicate (in your case you can probably only flag as dup). The systems doesn't come back and revises the review audit fail (alas), but at  least there is chance to get the thing out of the system for others. I voted to close like NathanOliver did.

Comment: Question is now dupe'd.

Comment: Dupe-flagging in Triage is inherently problematic. If the queue disagrees (as is often the case; if only the last one or two reviewers even have a chance to see your flag and comment, the outcome is unlikely to switch to Unsalvageable), your flag is **immediately** disputed and therefore dismissed, and I think it even blows away the auto-comment. That's not very good for anyone. [My advice at present](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/4099598) is to avoid dupe-flagging in all but blatantly-obvious cases where lots of reviewers will consider it a potential dupe.